# How to apply in condition like 'string' in data['column'] in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataset of Netflix shows. I want to filter the records based on:

```
data.loc[(data.type=='Movie') & (data.genre=='Action') & ('taxi' in str(data.description))]
```

There are no syntax errors in the above command however it`s not working as per my assumptions.

The condition that is causing the problem is:

```
('taxi' in str(data.description)
```

Comment: Run it one condition at a time. Does the last condition is the one that causes the error?

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is the last condition that is causing the problem.

Comment: Why don't you change it to: data.description=='taxi'?

Comment: The description is a long string. I want to test if the string contains the substring 'taxi' in it.
Example description of a record that should appear:
A taxi driver, a gangster and an athlete strug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
data.loc[(data.type == 'Movie') & (data.genre == 'Action') & data.description.str.contains('taxi')]
```

---

To understand why your code doesn't run check first the output of `print(str(data.description))`. What does it produce? What is the output of `print('taxi' in str(data.description))`? Do you understand what is happening?

Comment: Thanks, I tried both. However, I`m still a bit confused about the str(data.description). It seems that it returns tha str object against each entry in the data.descritption column. However.
The actual (len) records are:7787 
The len(str(data.description)) is 684. Can you kindly explain this.

Comment: @UmairMayo `str(data.description)` produces a single string, the string representation of the column `description`. Then, `'taxi' in str(data.description)` is checking if that single string contains the substring `'taxi'`. Therefore it produces a single boolean, `True` or `False`, not a boolean mask as you want. `Series.str.contains` performs that substring check row-wise over the column's string values, producing a valid boolean mask to be used as a condition

Comment: Thanks, but what about the len(str(data.description)) is 684? The total characters in the string. But it can`t be that as there are 7787 records and each record has a description.

Comment: Well, that I can't confirm and explain since I don't have access to the data... Are you sure about that? Maybe there lots of values that are empty strings. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the post description, so we can reproduce the same problem and help you (provide a sample of data and the minimal code which allow us to reproduce the same behaviour, you don't need and shouldn't post the full dataset)

Comment: @UmairMayo why did you accept the other answer btw? It's identical to mine, and I am trying to help you further by explaining the source of your problems

Comment: I`m sorry @Rodalm, I`m new to StackOverflow.  I thought I can mark multiple answers as correct, however, it was just my assumption. Thanks for your precious time, it was really helpful, and thanks to both of you.

Comment: @UmairMayo No worries, no need to apologize. You can only accept one answer but you upvote multiple ones! And don't get me wrong, you are free to accept the answer you feel like without having to justify yourself ;) I just found the sudden change strange! I'm glad I was able to help! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.loc[(data.type=='Movie') & (data.genre=='Action') & (data.description.str.contains('taxi')}]
```